# is there a way to open mail client (like thunderbird) and attach file with command line in Windows 10?

Tags: thunderbird

Well the title speaks for itself.

`thunderbird -compose` is not recognized in windows 10 for me and `mailto:?` option does not support attachments.

Is there a way to open email client with attachment? (does not have to be a command line)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Run thunderbird from its own directory:

```
c:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird>thunderbird -compose "attachment='C:\temp\file.txt'"
```